# For-loop not working as intended

Tags: c, for-loop

When I run this code, the `printf()` function seems to give a random large number, as if it is calling an array that is out of bounds. What is going on here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int test_num = 1000;
    int factors[16];

    for(int i = 1, j = 0; i < test_num; i++, j++) {
        if(test_num % i == 0)
            factors[j] = i;
    }

    printf("%d", factors[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Question: How do you know `factors[2]` was ever assigned?

Comment: What are you expecting? 4?

Comment: You're incrementing `j` in lockstep with `i`, not in the `if` statement.

Comment: Suggest you change `int factors[16];` to `int factors[16] = {0};` in order to initialize the array elements to zero.

Comment: when `j` is 2, `i` is 3. `1000 % 3 != 0`, so j[2] is never assigned to.

Comment: Also note in your code that j will be larger than 15 when you assign a value to your array in several cases, so your code will assign a value to a location past then end of the array `factors`.

Comment: I wrote j[2], but meant factors[2] (unfortunately I can't edit the comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, the problem is that you are incrementing `j` even when you don't assign `i`.

The sequence of factors you get is 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, ... You probably want to assign those to the indices 0-5 (inclusive), not 0, 1, 3, 4, 7, 9, etc.

Change your loop as follows:

```
for(int i = 1, j = 0; i < test_num && j < 16; i++) {
    if(test_num % i == 0) {
        factors[j] = i;
        j++;
    }
}
```

The main point is only to increment `j` when `i` fits your criterion. You also want to make sure that you don't go out of bounds (`&& j < 16`).

Answer (score 0):

If you print out `i` and `j` in the loop, notice that `j` is never 2.

Thus, `factors[2]` is never initialized, so you will print out junk.

Comment: `j` is `2` the third iteration.  Do you mean to say that when `i == 3` and `j == 2` the expression `1000 % 3 == 0` is `false`?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, what I'm asking is, why do you say `notice that j is never 2` when `j == 2` the third iteration.

Answer (score 0):

When `j == 2`, `i == 3` and `1000 % 3` does not equal 0. It equals 1. Not passing your `if` statement condition. Therefore `factors[2]` will be undefined (since you didn't initialize your array). Hence the large number.